# How can I connect my JavaScript function to the HTML button?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to connect my functions in a JavaScript file to a button in HTML and I can't figure out how to get them to connect after trying various things.

What I need is for the alert to appear (as written in the.js file) simply from pressing the first button on the web page.

[Here is my function within the class of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q26XM.png)

[And here is the latest attempt of many different ways I've tried to connect the function to the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZLxw.png)

Comment: "_The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem._"

Answer (score 2):

u call it with onClick

`<button onclick={YOUR FUNCTION() }>Continue</button>`